# If $(s_n)$ converges to $s$, then $(\lvert s_n\rvert)$ converges to $\lvert s\rvert$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Question:

> If $(s_n)$ converges to $s$, then $(\lvert s_n\rvert)$ converges to $\lvert s\rvert$. Prove or give a counterexample.

---

Attempt:

> The statement is true because if $(\lvert s_n\rvert)$ converges to $\lvert s\rvert$, then given any $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq N$ we have that $\lvert \lvert s_n\rvert-\lvert s\rvert\rvert <\epsilon$, but $\lvert \lvert s_n\rvert-\lvert s\rvert\rvert \leq\lvert s_n-s\rvert$ by the reverse triangle inequality, and by assumption given any $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq N$ we have that $\lvert s_n-s\rvert <\epsilon$; hence
>   $$\lvert \lvert s_n\rvert -\lvert s\rvert \rvert\leq \lvert s_n-s\rvert<\epsilon.$$

Comment: Why do you write $0<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$? You actually do not need it, I think. You know that for $N$ large $\vert s_n -s \vert$ is small; then use reverse triangular inequality and you conclude.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate more eloquently?

Comment: I have expanded my previous comment into an answer.

Comment: $f(x)=|x|$ is a continuous function

Comment: You're my Superman, clark.

Comment: @Loie Lois,is that you?

Comment: Ha ha ha! Very funny.

Comment: Looks fine, what is the question?

Comment: So it means that every conditionally convergent series is absolutely convergent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the hypothesis you know that fixed any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $n>N$ implies $\vert s-s_n \vert <\varepsilon$.

By reverse triangular inequality, you get that
$$
\vert \vert s_n \vert - \vert s \vert \vert \le \vert s-s_n\vert < \varepsilon
$$
if $n >N$. This is equivalent to say $\vert s_n \vert \to \vert s \vert$, which is the claim. Hope this can help.

Comment: Yeah? How's my attempt?

Comment: Your attempt is now fine, the idea is the same as mine. And of course, the main thing we use is the continuity of $\vert \cdot \vert$, as clark's comment pointed out.

Comment: Ah, I see. Why is the continuity of $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ of importance here, just to get things clear.

Comment: The reverse triangular inequality is essentially the same of continuity of $\vert \cdot \vert$.